# Download *.deb file with HttpURLConnection issue

Tags: java, ubuntu

I try to implement download function with HttpURLConnection and function work, but when the file suffix is ".deb" e.g. file1.deb, file2.deb, download the file is not complete.

why?

this my code

```
DownloadInfo downloadFile(String source, String saveDirectory)throws HTTPException {

    URL url = new URL(source);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new HTTPException(responseCode);
    }

    String httpContent = getResponseHeadContent(connection);

    Path saveFilePath = produceSavePath(source, saveDirectory);
    Files.copy(connection.getInputStream(), saveFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    connection.disconnect();

    DownloadInfo info = new DownloadInfo();
    info.setFilePath(saveFilePath);
    info.setHttpHeadContent(httpContent);

    return info;
}
```

Comment: @mpromonet thanks your answer, but I mean the file suffix is ".deb", then download success, but the file is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason because of link server is IIS. IIS does not serve the unknown file type, then ".deb" not in MIME type. I must manual to add it.